# Pyqgis action when something is selected

Tags: pyqgis

I want to make a pyqgis module that will perform an action similar to Identify tool. 
For example there is a tiny qt widget with a text box that is opened until user decide to close it manually. When user selects feature(s) of some layer, script immediately reads feature's attributes and print it in a text box. As soon as user selects another feature, widget's text will also change according to current selection. 
Is there some `onSelectionChange()` method for such actions?

Comment: Yes, see the [docs](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#ac32339abf885be1ed2262646e975dd87).

Comment: It's the layers signal you have to catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there definately is,

In initGui in one of my plugins, I have

```
self.iface.mapCanvas().selectionChanged.connect(self.markselected)
```

Then in markselected, I do: (self.view.layer is defined elsewhere)

```
def markselected(self):
    if self.view.layer==None: 
        return
    try:
        sels=self.view.layer.selectedFeatures() # The selected features in the active (from this plugin's point of view) layer
        n=len(sels)
        if n>0:
            for sel in sels:
               (process selected items)
```

Works like a charm.